# Repeating same statements in some regular time?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Im new to Logic Apps , is there any way to use Logic App or trigger logic app in frequent regular intervals of time i.e something like recurrence?
If we can do , then can anyone provide an example on how to do it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it, If you want default templates then you should use Consumption plan while creating your logic app then in default templates select Recurrence as below:

[image]

Then you will get a recurrence tab where you can perform recurring operations:

[image]